# Graph: visit only those nodes which maximize utility function

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, graph-theory

At first I had a problem from different domain, but now it is simplified and converted to a graph one.

Graph is

- bidirectional
- fully connected
- each vertex has positive cost
- each edge has negative cost
- start and finish vertex is the same

I need to traverse only those nodes which maximize total utility cost.

**Does it sound like any well-known graph problem?**

Example:

```
V = {A, B, C}

vertex points = {0, 6, 5}

edge cost = {[A,B]=-8, [A,C]=-2, [B,C]=-10}
```

So solution: is to visit vertex `C` only and come back. It would give 1 point in total.

If vertex is visited, it points become 0.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but in the case of there is a positive loop, is your problem well defined?

Comment: @ZiyaoWei, once you visit a vertex, it points become 0.

Comment: Also, in the example, after C is visited (starting from A, is it?), how do we get back since the edges are unidirectional (should that be bidirectional?)?

Comment: @ZiyaoWei, yes, sorry for my English :) I have updated the question with your comments.

Comment: Could you explain what a utility function is? I'm not familiar with that concept and google doesn't turn anything up either.

Comment: @G.Bach, it is just sum of vertex points and edge cost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should be NP-hard for general graphs, because it can be rephrased as the longest path problem. To see how, we change the costs of the edges and vertices.

Let `c(e)` be the cost of edge `e`, let `e = {u,v}` and `c(u), c(v)` be the costs of vertices `u` and `v`, respectively. Set the new cost of each edge to `c_new(e) = c(e) + 1/2*(c(u)+c(v))`. The intuition behind this is that on your cycle from a vertex to itself, you use 2 edges incident with each vertex you pass, so you can only count half the cost of the vertex for each edge; think of it as paying half the cost at arrival and the other half when leaving the vertex.

After you changed the costs of the edges, you can ignore vertex costs since they will now be considered in the costs of the edges. Your problem now becomes to find a simple path that maximizes the sum of its edge weights, which is the NP-hard problem known as longest path problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is called the prize-collecting traveling salesman problem.

Comment: +1 also, any idea how to solve it reasonable fast? Googling gives lot of papers with terrible maths :)